# Javascript to edit CSS Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am having trouble getting my JavaScript code to change the CSS style of my article element. I have this in the opening tag for my article element:
'''

```
<img id="n1" onmouseover="visible('c1')" src="img/musicnote1.png" alt="Music Note">
```

'''
and then at the bottom of my body section I have my script tag:
'''

```
<script>
    function visible(a){
        document.getElementById(a).style.display = initial;
        document.getElementById('default').style.display = none;
    }
</script>
```

'''
I am trying to make the 'c1' article appear and the 'default' article disappear when the user hovers over the image. Neither of these actions are working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need to assign strings as attributes:

```
<script>
    function visible(a){
        document.getElementById(a).style.display = 'initial';
        document.getElementById('default').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```